# Simple PHP Modules .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have starting creating a simple module system to help me build and visualise how all the pages of my application are going to be organised behind the scenes.

I'm starting to feel this isn't a very good way of achieving this as I will end up with a huge .htaccess file to rewrite all urls for each module.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^login$ index.php?page=login
```

Each module should have it's own controller, so that it is seperate from other module code, and any page inside any module should be able to access configuration array values from within the root index.php file.

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    switch($_GET['page']) {
        case 'login':
            $page = 'modules/default/login.php';
        break;
    }
} else {
    $page = 'modules/default/homepage.php';
}

include($page);

?>
```

I'm having issues as to what will happen when I add an account module that contains other pages. e.g. /account or /account/profile

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    switch($_GET['page']) {
        case 'settings':
            $page = 'modules/account/settings/index.php';
        break;
    }
} else {
    $page = 'modules/account/index.php';
}

include($page);

?>
```

Is there a better way this can be done?
Hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Better to have your rule to catch all URIs that are not files or directories like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then use `$_GET['page']` parameter to get all the URI values in your PHP code.